# Send email using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am new to PL/SQL code and looking for some help here.
I am working on an APEX Tool with PL/SQL query to send an email.

From Recipient is considered as APP_USER while TO recipient will be based on user input.
Below is the code I used, but I get an error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error:
>   ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

```
DECLARE    
P5_NEW  varchar2(80);
begin
apex_mail.send(
   p_from               => 'test@test.com',
   p_to                 =>  &P5_NEW.,
   subject              => 'Test Mail',
   message              => 'Hello World'
end;
```

I want to trigger an email the moment send (Button) is clicked

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to provide clarifications or more details.

Comment: `subject` and `message` don't seem to be valid parameters for [apex_mail.send()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI342). Are you sure the posted code is the code you're using? Or please confirm which version of APEX you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Check you datatype in you parameters.